# Как можно изменить цвет таблицы с текстом в таблице?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Создаю таблицу, как можно изменить цвет таблицы и цвет текста в таблицах?

```
    self.tableResultLeft = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableResultLeft.setObjectName("tableResultLeft")
    self.tableResultLeft.setColumnCount(3)
    self.tableResultLeft.setRowCount(3)
```

Может ещё кто подскажет, как сделать clicked у QLabel, то голову сломал не могу найти этот метод у него или как можно click повесить на QLabel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Достаточно просто можете применить встроенную в Qt [таблицу стилей (qss)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html)

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
import sys


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(440, 180)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QTableWidget{
                background-color: #000;
                color: #fff;
            }

        """)
        self.table.setColumnCount(4)
        for i in range(4):
            self.table.insertRow(0)
            for j in range(4):
                self.table.setItem(0, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(j)))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

Или использовать альтернативу создавая каждый элемент `QTableWidgetItem` и применять к нему цвет фона и цвет текста

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
import sys


class Main(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.resize(440, 180)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.table.setColumnCount(4)
        for i in range(4):
            self.table.insertRow(0)
            for j in range(4):
                a = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(j))
                a.setForeground(QtGui.QColor("#fff"))
                a.setBackground(QtGui.QColor("#000"))
                self.table.setItem(0, j, a)
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```